# Play Framework. Routes. Error: "not enough arguments for method at..."

Tags: routes, playframework-2.1

There are my routes. Second one is commented.

```
GET         /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

#GET         /partials/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/partials", file)
```

( **What I want is:**  to make my html files that are located inside `"/public/partials"` folder to be available through the web, same way as it's made for `assets` )

As soon as **I uncomment 2nd line** - it will get errors due to this line (from my `index.scala.html`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

Error is like here:

> not enough arguments for method at: (path: String, file:
>   String)play.api.mvc.Call. Unspecified value parameter file.

**Q:** What's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

**Another words:** I want to make my url shorter by providing that mapping. Otherwise I have to use this url: `'assets/partials/welcome.html'` instead of that one (that I would like to use): `'partials/welcome.html'`.

Just one more mapping that would make my urls shorter.

It make sense when I need to reach those from JS part, it's like having two applications in one (1.play one, 2. js one), there too routings, two roots. For JS one I'm assuming that I'm already in /public (or in assets) - this is a root for js app.

And I wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [play docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Assets):

**Reverse routing for public assets**

As for any controller mapped in the routes file, a reverse controller is created in `controllers.routes.Assets`. You use this to reverse the URL needed to fetch a public resource. For example, from a template:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.js")"></script>
```

This will produce the following result:

```
<script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Note that we don’t specify the first `folder` parameter when we reverse the route. This is because our routes file defines a single mapping for the Assets.at action, where the folder parameter is fixed. So it doesn’t need to be specified explicitly.

However, if you define two mappings for the Assets.at action, like this:

```
GET  /javascripts/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
GET  /images/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)
```

Then you will need to specify both parameters when using the reverse router:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "jquery.js")"></script>
<image src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images", "logo.png")">
```

Any static html in the public/partials directory would be publicly available at /assets/partials/someHtml.html. So strictly speaking, you don't need the /partials/*file route

Comment: I know, but I want to make my url shorter by providing that mapping. Otherwise I have to use this url: 'assets/partials/welcome.html' instead of that one: 'partials/welcome.html'. Just one more mapping that would make my urls shorter. It make sense when I need to reach those from JS part, it's like having two applications in one (1.play one, 2. js one), there too routings, two roots. For JS one I'm assuming that I'm already in /public (or in assets) - this is a root for js app. And I wondered why it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps this is clear to you already but if you define a second mapping for the Assets.at action then you need to specify the path parameter when using the reverse router. This is because the path is now ambiguous. So instead of being able to use @routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css") you have to use @routes.Assets.at("/public", "stylesheets/main.css")

Comment: Yeah. I see. I would better use one route definition and will 'suffer' having one more word in url than will be putting one more param to each asset-url.

Comment: This solution gives me: `[MatchError: (public/css,bootstrap.min.css) (of class scala.Tuple2)]`

Comment: I believe I hit a play bug/quirk in this area (2.4.2 and 2.5.0).  If you have two routes files in conf folder, multiplicity of asset routes should be the same in both files.  That means, if you have multiple asset routes in one file, the other file also should have multiple asset routes. Otherwise, play produces a misleading error where you use the reverse routing in html template. I had two asset routes in main app `routes` file and one in `test.routes`. I was then receiving 'not enough arguments' error for one argument version of `@routes.Assets.at()` and 'too many arguments' for the other.